# Почему не работает форма php

Tags: php, html

Форма не отправляет письмо на адрес. При отправке переходит на страницу с form.php, но print не выводится. Консоль чистая. Задолбался уже((

```html
<form id="main-form" method="POST" action="form.php">
            <p>Выберите удобный способ связи, мы перезвоним либо напишем и вы сможете задать все интересующие вас вопросы. Так-же произведем рассчет стоимости вашего будущего видео-ролика</p>
        
            <div class="radio__container">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="phone" checked>
                <span><img src="assets/img/links/1.png"></span>
              </label>
        
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="whatsapp" checked>
                <span><img src="assets/img/links/2.png"></span>
              </label>
        
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="viber" checked>
                <span><img src="assets/img/links/viber.png"></span>
              </label>
        
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="telegram" checked>
                <span><img src="assets/img/links/3.png"></span>
              </label>
        
        
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="vk" checked>
                <span><img src="assets/img/links/4.png"></span>
              </label>
        
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="skype" checked>
                <span><img src="assets/img/links/5.png"></span>
              </label>
        
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="email" checked>
                <span><img src="assets/img/links/6.png"></span>
              </label>
        
            </div>
        
            <input type="text" required placeholder="Укажите ваш мобильный" name="phone" id="phone">
            <input type="text" required placeholder="Укажите ваш url во Вконтакте" name="vk" id="vk">
            <input type="text" required placeholder="Укажите ваш логин Skype" name="skype" id="skype">
            <input type="text" required placeholder="Укажите ваш email" name="email" id="email">
        
            <input type="text" required placeholder="Укажите ваше имя" name="name" id="name">
        
            <input type="submit" value="Запросить звонок" id="submit">
          </form>
```

```
<?
// ----------------------------конфигурация-------------------------- //

$adminemail="mgroup258@gmail.com";  // e-mail админа
$backurl1="http://pasha";
// Принимаем данные с формы
$email=$_POST["email"];
$phone=$_POST["phone"];
$vk=$_POST["vk"];
$skype=$_POST["skype"];
$name=$_POST["name"];
$messenger=$_POST["messager"]

$msg="name:". $name . "
phone:" . $phone . "
email:" . $email . "
vk:" . $vk . "
skype:" . $skype . "
messager:" . $messager . "";
mail("$adminemail", "Сообщение от $email", "$msg");

print "<script language='Javascript'><!-- 
function reload() {location = \"$backurl1\"
}; setTimeout('reload()', 100); 
//--></script> 
<p>Сообщение отправлено!</p>";
exit;

?>
```

Comment: а как выглядит часть на фронте?

Comment: Что за дичь вы тут пишете - `'reload()'`? У вас где-то объявлена функция `reload()`?

Comment: `setTimeout(window.location.href="/",100)` вместо вашего `reload()`